# I want to each test-suite in a new chrome instance in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I am testing my non-angular app with the protractor.
I have 40 test-suites including login Test. These all test-suites are in diffrent files.

```
    export.config :{
    spec:[
    'testSuite1.js',
    'testSuite2.js',
    'testSuite3.js',
    'testSuite4.js',
    ...
    ...
    'testSuite38.js',
    'testSuite39.js',
    'testSuite40.js',
    ]
}
```

I want to start each 10 test-suite in a new chrome browser windows.
Like when I run, `protractor conf.js` in commandLine, It should start open 4 windows with all 40 test suites starting on those.

10 on each instance.

I have got some Idea as-

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: 'true',
    maxInstances: 4
  },
```

but not able to do.

**UPDATE**
I have tried as [Ernst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8683679/ernst-zwingli) described but No Success-

```
 Started Selenium server: 127.0.0.1:4444
 Running "protractor:start" (protractor)
 task [17:04:00] W/launcher - You have specified both capabilities and multiCapabilities. This will result in capabilities being ignored [17:04:00] I/launcher - Running 0 instances of WebDriver
 E:\Work\test>
```

Comment: do you want to achieve parallel execution?

Comment: [Sudharsan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6405587/sudharsan-selvaraj) , I have updated my question,first see that, and Yes I want to acheive parallel execution.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this could work for you.

You can add specific `spec`'s per capability or also exclude some.
And as you may "repeat the same capabilities" within `multiCapabilities`, I'd suggest something like this:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: 'true',
    maxInstances: 4
    spec: ['spec_1.js', ... , 'spec_10.js'] //evtl. specify a path with them and do ../path/*.js
},{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: 'true',
    maxInstances: 4
    spec: ['spec_11.js', ... , 'spec_20.js'] //evtl. specify a path with them and do ../path/*.js
}, { 
    //same for the other test suites.
}],
```

Check the `capabilities` part of the [official lib/config.ts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) for more details.

As I have no experience with those options myself, you'll need to try a bit.

Let me know, if it leaded to a solution for you.

Comment: Also this might be useful to reduce duplication - https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L338

Comment: The warning-message is pretty clear: use either `multiCapabilities` or `Capabilities`, but not both of them. Therefore comment your `Capabilities`-section. Further than that I don't see any error or further added information in your question, that would explain, why your tests didn't start (if they didn't).

Comment: any success or new error message with commenting out `capabilities`, only going with `multiCapabilities`?